# Javascript Discount Calculation for each item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an existing document that has pre existing pricing. So on the page I have a bunch of elements for example price here with each one having different pricing of course.

How can I write a jquery/javascript script to take each of those prices and divide them by 24 and then append a p tag that shows that calculation, this should happen on page load.

so far i have this, just testing it on click but it gives me the same answer for each, which is the very first occurrence of the price divided by 24.

for ex if they price is 1600, or 500, or 100000 the answer it gives me is always based on 1600.

```
  $(".button").click(function () {
            var value = $('.price').text();
            var price = parseFloat(value)/24;
            $('.price').append('<p>' + price + '</p>');
        });
```

Can someone help please?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In the above code, your use of the `text()` method selects only the first element with the class price.

You need to loop over all the elements with the class price.

```
  $(".button").click(function () {
            $('.price').each(function(index, el) {
                var price = parseFloat($(el).text())/24;
                $(el).append('<p>' + price + '</p>');
            });
        });
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Btw what if these price tags were all the last child of a div called row, how could I target them that way? for some reason the existing html markup has the same classes for pretty much all the pricing, but I only need to target just the last ones.

Comment: I think what you're looking is `.last()` https://api.jquery.com/last/

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `var value = $('.price').text();` it selects the first price it finds.
You should use a variable in the event handler to get access to the item that was clicked on. Then get the price from that.

Assuming the button has a descendant with a price class :

```
$(".button").click(function (e) {
    var value = $(event.currenttarget).find(".price")
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the following implementation should work:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach(element => {
  const priceElement = element.querySelector('.price');
  
  const price = parseFloat(priceElement.textContent) / 24;

  const childElement = document.createElement('p');
  childElement.textContent = price;

  priceElement.appendChild(childElement);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(".button").click(function () {
             $('.price').each(function(p){
           $('.price')[p].innerHTML =  $('.price')[p].innerHTML/24});
          
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='price button'>240</div>
<div class='price'>480</div>
```